# suppose that $a_1 \geq \dotsb \geq a_k$ and that $\lim_{k\to\infty} a_k=0$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

> Suppose that $a_1\geq \dotsb \geq a_k\geq \dotsb \geq 0$ and that 
>   $\lim_{k\to\infty} a_k = 0$.
>   Let 
>   $$S_N = \sum_{k=1}^N(-1)^{k+1}a_k.$$
>   Show that
>   $$\left|\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^{k+1}a_k-S_N\right|<a_N.$$

[Source.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whttB.png)

I'm stuck in this question and don't know how start any help please

Comment: The claim is false. Try $a_1=a_2=1$, $a_3=a_4=\ldots = 0$ and $N=1$.

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: It clearly can't be true if any $a_k=0$, because it is possible for $|z|<0$. @HagenvonEitzen

Comment: how ???, as you see in question it asked about prove the next statement

Comment: I don't see why downvoting is warranted here. It looks like OP has stumbled upon this (ill-posed) excercise.

Comment: please help , I need really help

Comment: @user155971 As Hagen implied and Thomas explicitly stated, the claim can be false if (and only if) there is a $k$ with $a_k = 0$, and hence $a_n = 0$ for all $n \geqslant k$. Then it's false for all $N \geqslant k$, since then both sides of the inequality are $0$. You get a true claim if either you add the assumption that $a_k > 0$ for all $k$, or you make the inequality non-strict, $\lvert\dotsc\rvert \leqslant a_N$.